# google maps polygons - overlay

Tags: google-maps, polygons

I am attempting to implement a "negative" overlay on my google maps, similar to the effect that you get at estately.com. Basically, I have successfully drawn up mapping polygons from the KML data I've gathered. When there are multiple paths, they draw up just fine.

So, modeling the example I have, first I create a set of polyLines around my area from polygonCoords (which is an array of arrays of LatLng objects):

```
for (var d = 0 ; d < polygonCoords.length ; d++) 
{
  var b = new google.maps.Polyline( {
                                    path: polygonCoords[d],
                                    strokeWeight: 4,
                                    strokeColor: "#4F6D8F",
                                    strokeOpacity: 1,
                                    map: map
                                   });
}
```

I have a "negative space" polygon defined by:

```
function negativeSpaceBoundary()
{
  return [new google.maps.LatLng(10, -170), 
          new google.maps.LatLng(10, -50), 
          new google.maps.LatLng(80, -50), 
          new google.maps.LatLng(80, -170), 
          new google.maps.LatLng(10, -170)]
};
```

So, I unshift that negative space polygon into my polygonCoords array, and attempt
to draw the polygon:

```
negativeSpace = new google.maps.Polygon( {
                                           path: polygonCoords,
                                           strokeWeight: 0,
                                           strokeOpacity: 1,
                                           strokeColor: "#4F6D8F",
                                           fillColor: "#000000",
                                           fillOpacity: 0.2,
                                           clickable: false,
                                           map: map
                                         });
```

Basically, what I'm hoping will happen is that my initial set of polyLines will "punch
a hole" in the negative space polygon, so that there is essentially no overlay covering
my city boundary. If you go to estately.com, and search for "Paradise Valley, AZ", you
can see the effect.

I have tried several variations (Polygons vs Polylines, different fill colors and 
opacities, etc), but nothing achieves the effect displayed in my sample.

Any ideas? Using the v3 API, BTW.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Both paths need to be in the same polygon.  The inner hole path winding direction needs to be opposite the outer path.

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_donut.html

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_nosidebar.html?lat=37.155939&lng=-79.497071&zoom=6&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/virginia_inverted_kml.xml

[Your polygon](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_complex_hole.html) (all of the "holes" seem to be the same).

Comment: I believe that is what I have in place. When drawing the overlay,
I have both prepended (unshift) and appended the surrounding polygon before drawing it. Essentially, my polygon looks like:
`[
  [surround: (10, -170),(80, -170),(80, -50),(10, -50),(10, -170)]
  [boundary: (28.646438, 80.84433100000001), (28.642874, 80.84357699999998), (28.642874, 80.84317699999997) ...]
]
`

I think I get your "winding direction needs to be opposite" - I have tried reversing
the outer hole coordinate directions and no go...


Thanks for the suggestions, I'll keep digging.

Comment: By the way, the second example (buttons) don't seem to work in Firefox.

Comment: The buttons don't work at all, I put it up as an example of a complicated hole.

Comment: If you have a complete set of coordinates for the inner hole, we might be able to help more (or even a link to a live page or jsfiddle that shows the problem).

Comment: Thanks! I grabbed some code from the samples sites I found for polygon convex-ness and winding direction. The sample I'm working with as a total of five polygons - the outer, and 4 "inner". (It's the map of titusville, fl generated from census data).  The results are:
`0::Convex? 1, Wind: 16800
1::Convex? -1, Wind: -0.012936066837028193
2::Convex? -1, Wind: -0.012936066837028193
3::Convex? -1, Wind: -0.012936066837028193
4::Convex? -1, Wind: -0.012936066837028193`
I'll post access to a file with the coordinate sets in it in a second

Comment: YOu can get the set of coordinates at   http://diamondw.net/coords.php    Let me know if there's a better way of giving you access.

Comment: Ok, I thjink I found the problem... the nested polygons I got from the Census info are breaking things. If I strip that set down to just the first one, i works (though all the "parts" might not be there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just discovered the same thing (the first one works): http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_complex_hole.html

Comment: You sure all the other paths aren't the same?

Comment: Yeah, looks like that is part of the issue. Minor issue with there being multiple "outer" polygons.