# Multipolygon creating the hole effect with google map V3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon

We have multipolygon and where the first polygon will be the biggest one and rest will be smaller ones. We have now managed to do something below. The issue is that we want the rest of the polygon to create like hole effect into the first big polygon. We have read this [google maps polygons - overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504788/google-maps-polygons-overlay) but dont get how achieve this. Lots of places they talk about this "inner hole path winding direction needs to be opposite the outer path." How to get this done based on my lat long?

```
 var mps = ["MULTIPOLYGON((4 47,19.1 50.1,18.1 60,4 47),(3.9 46.9,28.5 46.5,5 30,3.9 46.9))", "MULTIPOLYGON((50 57,20.1 47.1,1 1,50 57),(11.9 46.9,31.5 46.5,50 1,11.9 46.9))"];
        for(i in mps){
            var lines = drawPoly(mps[i].replace("MULTIPOLYGON",""));
            for(k=0;k<lines.length;k++){
                lines[k].setMap(map);
            }
            lines.length = 0;
        }     


function drawPoly(multipolygonWKT){
        var polylines = [];
        var toReturn = [];

        var formattedValues = multipolygonWKT.replace("))", "");
             formattedValues = formattedValues.replace("((", "");


        var linesCoords = formattedValues.split("),(");



        for(i=0;i<linesCoords.length;i++){
            polylines[i] = [];
            var singleLine = linesCoords[i].split(",");

            for(j=0;j<singleLine.length;j++){
                var coordinates = singleLine[j].split(" ");
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coordinates[1]), parseFloat(coordinates[0]));

                polylines[i].push(latlng);

            }
        }

    //by now you should have the polylines array filled with arrays that hold the coordinates of the polylines of the multipolyline
    //lets loop thru this array

    for(k=0;k<polylines.length;k++){
        var line = polylines[k];
        if(k==0){
            toReturn.push(new google.maps.Polygon({
                                                paths: line,
                                                strokeColor: '#FF00FF',
                                                strokeOpacity: 0,
                                                strokeWeight: 6,
                                                fillColor: '#1E90FF',
                                                fillOpacity: 0,
                                                zIndex:1                                                        
            }));
        }
        else if(k>0)
        {
            toReturn.push(
                new google.maps.Polygon({
                                                paths: line,
                                                strokeColor: '#1122AA',
                                                strokeOpacity: 1,
                                                strokeWeight: 2,                                                   
                                                zIndex:1    
                })                                    
            );
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
    }
```

Comment: possible dupplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027094/holes-in-a-polygon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "holes" need to be a path in the outside polygon, not another google.maps.Polygon

[example of complex polygon with different paths and winding directions](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_donutD.html)

You need to start with polygons that have holes in them (your MULTIPOLYGON's don't):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_polygonHoles.html

Comment: so how to achieve that or to combine into the outside polygon any idea please?

Comment: Hi geocodezip, This link is superb http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_polygonHoles.html.It can work but I dont understand how it works I want to know further details first this line polylines[i] = []; just to clear the array. Then each of the polygon is push into this polylines[i].push(latlng); right? Then we do this outside the loop polys.push(new google.maps.Polygon({
                                            paths: polylines, so which array will be push as this is just stated as  paths: polylines? Another thing I just closed this whole thing yet it works.

Comment: Same goes to this one toReturn = new google.maps.Polygon({
                                            paths: polylines, which array goes in here?

Comment: I just made your existing code work, it is far from pretty or optimized.  The `polylines[i] = []` makes the "ith" element of the polylines array an empty array.  The Polygon.paths property is an array of arrays of google.maps.LatLng objects.  To make a hole, the outer path (usually paths[0]) needs to wind the opposite way as inner paths that define holes.

Comment: yes I am getting clearer now when you is an array of array so polylines consist of each of the polygon arrary. Surprisingly why when I comment this one /*polys.push(new google.maps.Polygon({paths: polylines,strokeColor: '#FF00FF',strokeOpacity: 0.8,strokeWeight: 2,fillColor: '#1E90FF',fillOpacity: 0.45,zIndex:1 }));*/ yes the whole shape comes out same so guess this part is not needed? This part is where I dont get it "To make a hole, the outer path (usually paths[0]) needs to wind the opposite way as inner paths that define holes". How is the paths[0] wind in oppose in this codes?